# phonegap QR/barcode generator plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, qr-code, barcode-scanner, cordova-plugins

I want to make an app that generates a barcode/qr image in phonegap for Ios. 
Is there any plugins existing for this?

If not, is there any JS/HTML5 scripts that can be used?

I tried google, but did not find much usefull info (found one for android, but need something for Ios)

Thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution A: web service

If your app can require an internet connection to generate QR codes, you can use a web service.

QR code example for URL `www.example.com`:

**Google Chart API (deprecated)**

```
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://www.example.com/&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|1
```

[image: QR code example]

**ZXing web service**

```
http://zxing.org/w/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://www.example.com/&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|1
```

[image: QR code example]

As mentioned by [Sean Owen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64174/sean-owen).

## Solution B: plugin

If you don't mind using a plugin, you can use the official BarcodeScanner plugin to generate (and read) codes.

- [BarcodeScanner plugin page](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/951)
- [BarcodeScanner documentation and source at Github](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/blob/c3090dc/README.md)

Comment: QR code support in the Google Chart server is going away in April 2015 (https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/). The zxing project actually ported the same QR code generation code and exposes a web service that supports the same args. Ex: http://zxing.org/w/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://www.example.com/&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|1